# "Read error Is a directory /home/ngaroe/.emacs-mail-crash-box"

Tags: gnus

The version of emacs I'm using is 27.1-r4 (Gentoo description).

My .gnus file is

```
(setq
    gnus-select-method '(nnmaildir ".maildir" (directory "~/.nnmaildir"))
    mail-sources '((maildir :path "~/.nnmaildir/" :subdirs ("cur" "new")))
;;; mail-source-delete-incoming t
 )
(setq gnus-secondary-select-methods nil)
(setq gnus-message-archive-group "nnmaildir+.maildir:archive")

(setq gnus-inhibit-user-auto-expire t)
```

The .maildir directory is `~/.nnmaildir/.maildir/`

On running `emacs -f gnus` I get

```
Reading incoming mail from maildir...
Processing mail from ~/.emacs-mail-crash-box...
Mail source (maildir :path ~/.nnmaildir/ :subdirs (cur new)) failed: (file-error Read error Is a directory /home/ngaroe/.emacs-mail-crash-box)
```

and `.emacs-mail-crash-box` is

```
ngaroe@lenovo ~ $ l .emacs-mail-crash-box/
total 24
4 drwx------  5 ngaroe ngaroe 4096 Dec  1  2019 ./
4 drwx------ 55 ngaroe ngaroe 4096 Apr 11 14:34 ../
4 drwx------  2 ngaroe ngaroe 4096 Dec  1  2019 cur/
4 -rw-------  1 ngaroe ngaroe   17 Dec  1  2019 .mu-prop
4 drwx------  2 ngaroe ngaroe 4096 Dec  1  2019 new/
4 drwx------  2 ngaroe ngaroe 4096 Dec  1  2019 tmp/
```

There was no `.emacs-mail-crash-box` before running emacs/gnus so it seems to have been an own goal...

What on earth is going on?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is ... delete the directory .emacs-mail-crash-box (saving a copy just in case), create a new empty file .emacs-mail-crash-box and rerun `emacs -f gnus` ...

Comment: Thanks for following up on your own question.  Could you please clarify what part of the question this post answers?  I'm guessing it resolves the "how do I make the errors go away" problem, but doesn't explain what's going on or why it works.

Comment: @Dan Sorry, the problem was that emacs/gnus creates .emacs-mail-crash-box as a directory and this can be bypassed by creating it as a file before running emacs/gnus. I don't know whether it's a bug or a feature -- a few months ago (not sure how long or the emacs version) the directory was created with just drw-r--r-- permissions so it couldn't read it and failed on this error so something has been  changed.

Comment: Please edit your answer and add the comment to it. Comments are not searchable and they are used mostly by other people asking you (as the provider of the answer) questions to clarify. But your clarifications should be part of the answer, not another comment.